# Mismatch in parameter count? but I'm fairly certain they match

Tags: sql, actionscript-3, sqlite, parameters, air

I'm running this in an Air app using SQLite. Trying to run a query and I'm getting this error, but it seems like what it's complaining about should not be the case unless I'm misunderstanding something.

details:'Mismatch in parameter count. Found 1 in SQL specified and 3 value(s) set in parameters property. Expecting values for ':PatientId'

SQL statement text:

```
SELECT DateTime, BolusTotal FROM Bolus 
WHERE DateTime >= ':Date :StartTime' 
AND DateTime < datetime(':Date :StartTime', '+24 hours') 
AND PatientID = :PatientId 
ORDER BY DateTime ASC
```

and the 3 parameters are set. :Date - 2011-04-03, :PatientId - 1, :StartTime - 00:00:00.

Am I missing something? Because I see 3 parameters in the SQL specified...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters in the single quotes are not being recognized as parameters - it thinks they are just parts of strings.  Only :PatientId is seen as a param.

You need to pass in a fully formatted datetime in the first case, and in the second, could just add the 24 outside of the call and pass that in as another argument.

Comment: Great!  Should have been obvious.. I got stuck because I was looking at an example that used single quotes instead of doublequotes to delineate the query string and that made me think that it was proper to put a parameter that was a string rather than an int inside quotes.